# How to re-arrange serial no on deleting rows

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a dynamic HTML table where on click on `add` I am adding item to my table and for each row I have one delete button, and on click I am deleting that row.

When I am clicking on `add` I am incriminating my `S_No` and placing it to S_No column.

**Issue**

Suppose I have created 5 rows and then I am deleting the 2nd one so it is showing 1,3,4,5 instead of 1,2,3,4.

**What I have tried**

But this one is not working fine.

```
this.tableDatas.forEach((element,index) => {
      alert(element)
       this.tableDatas.push({
        S_No:index + 1
         });
    });
```

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    S_No: Number,
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    amount: Number
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: [],
      S_No: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      let S_No = this.S_No++;
      this.tableDatas.push({
        S_No,
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 55
      });
    },
    btnOnDelete(key) {
      this.tableDatas.splice(key, 1);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sno">S No</th>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row" @delete="btnOnDelete(key)"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="S_No">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button @click="$emit('delete')">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: nothing wrong the way you delete data , what do you mean 1345 insted of 1234 ? do the deletedd one is not the right one ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 look I suppose I have 5 rows, and S_No is  1,2,3,4,5 Now I have deleted the row having S_No 2 so now the serial no is showing up as 1,3,4,5 because I have deleted 2 which I don't want, I want, after deleting row the serial no should be in serial only like if 2 is deleted then S_No should rearrange to 1,2,3,4 internally row 2 is deleted but I have to show correct serial No, Please check my UI you will understand.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it like looping again to your array to re arrange the keys. Maybe not the best solution but it will solve your question as of now. see code below

```
btnOnDelete(key) {
    this.tableDatas.splice(key, 1);

   this.tableDatas.forEach((element, index) => {
       element.S_No = index+1
   });
}
```

Comment: but your indexing start form 0 Can you check my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    S_No: Number,
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    amount: Number,
    index: Number
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: [],
      S_No: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      let S_No = this.S_No++;
      this.tableDatas.push({
        S_No,
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 55
      });
    },
    btnOnDelete(key) {
      this.tableDatas.splice(key, 1);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sno">S No</th>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row" :index="key" @delete="btnOnDelete(key)"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="index + 1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button @click="$emit('delete')">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: I I just check your answer and it is correct, I just have one doubt could you please clear it?

Comment: here  am creating new row once i click on `add` what I am trying to do is each time when i click on add the focus should be on new (latest) row only, can you give me some Idea how it will be done please

Comment: didn't clearly understand can you please clarify it again.

Comment: I want the focus on latest created row if I have created 3 rows then focus should be in 3rd rows input

Comment: 3rd row input means My rows are having input fields You can check on click I am creating rows which are having input fields

Comment: Yeah got it. So you mean latest row input field is focusing @manishthakur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206416/discussion-between-sabbir-and-manish-thakur).

Answer (score 0):

Use index of the parent component as the props for the child component. Once an element is deleted the index will also get updated automatically. Find the working solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kojur8x4/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: [],
      S_No: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      let S_No = this.S_No++;
      this.tableDatas.push({
        S_No,
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 55
      });
    },
    btnOnDelete(key) {
      this.tableDatas.splice(key, 1);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
})

Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    S_No: Number,
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    amount: Number,
    indexdata: Number
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sno">S No</th>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" :indexdata="key" v-bind.sync="row" @delete="btnOnDelete(key)"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="indexdata">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button @click="$emit('delete')">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```